# Copy R plot to clipboard with custom size

Tags: r, windows, graphics, rstudio, clipboard

Is there a way to get R / RStudio to copy a plot to the clipboard with a custom size?

RStudio has this function, but you have to define the size everytime and there is some extra clicking which I am sure is avoidable.

I tried my best with saving as jpeg or else with `file="clipboard"` and then - after plotting - `dev.off()`. No error messages, but also nothing in the clipboard.

Here is an example:

```
data(mtcars)
jpeg(file = "clipboard",width = 800, height = 600, units = "px", pointsize = 12,
     quality = 100,
     bg = "white", res = NA, family = "", restoreConsole = T)
hist(mtcars$mpg)
dev.off()
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: I haven't got RStudio, so can't test it, but you should be able to do something like `hist(mtcars$mpg); savePlot("clipboard","wmf")` but this doesn't generalise to other file formats.

Comment: The correct answer depends on the operating system which so far has no been offered.

Comment: e.g. on os x simply click on the plot window and hit `Cmd-C`. Not sure about Windows.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon there's a manual "copy" menu item in the Windows GUI, but my impression is that the OP wants a command-line tool.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't know the emoticon for embarrassed smiley, but imagine that's what I'm doing right now.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. Some more information:
- I am aware of the RStudio export. It works, but is too clickyclicky
- My OS is windows 7
- savePlot("clipboard","wmf") does not work, I get the error message 
"Error in savePlot("clipboard", type = "wmf") : 
  kann nur aus 'windows' Devices kopieren"
(Last line is something like "can only copy from 'windows' devices")

Comment: That's correct: you have to display the plot in a window before that'll work.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Ok. How to do this?

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221639/save-plot-without-showing-it-at-all

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way would be to be able to control the size in Rstudio, but as you have found out yourself from the Rstudio-website, Rstudio doesn't support that. The following code saves your plot to wmf. There is also a workaround to a save to bitmap, which involves some clicking, but at least you don't have to specify the size any more:

```
data(mtcars)
windows(800, 600, pointsize = 12) #opens a separate window with the size you want 
hist(mtcars$mpg) #draw to this (active) window
savePlot("clipboard", type="wmf") #saves plot to WMF
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be impossible to save to `jpg` format to the clipboard. You can copy it to a bitmap by going to this window, click `CTRL-C` and the graph is on the clipboard as bitmap with 800:600.

EDIT:
The `windows` command only works on Windows.
For **Mac**, it should be replaced by: `quartz(width=8,height=6,pointsize=12,dpi=100)` (width/height in inches!)

For **linux** try `x11(width=8,height=6,pointsize=12,dpi=100)` (untested).

Comment: That "windows"-approach did the trick! This avoids the rescaling. Thanks RHA for the support!

Comment: Encountered the error `Error: could not find function "windows"`.

Comment: @ShretaGhimire then you are probably not working on windows, but on mac or linux. On mac, try `quartz(width=800,height=600,pointsize=12)`, but I can't it test today because I have no access to a mac.

Comment: @RHA i am using RStudio on lInux.

Comment: @ShretaGhimire I don't know how to open a graphics device in linux, but some googling suggests it may be `x11(width=800,height=600,pointsize=12)`

Comment: type="wmf" is not needed in savePlot("clipboard", type="wmf"). @RHA

Comment: @Andrew: You are right, it's the default and to only option for clipboard. I added it to make extra clear that this is a vector format that gets copied. You (or anyone else) wouldn't by any change know how to copy a bitmap (or why it is not possible)?

Comment: @RHA I wonder how this would work with RStudio Server (on a linux) machine? `x11()` tells me it's `unable to start device X11cairo`

Comment: @stats-hb I have no idea. The X11 command is apparently recognized, but fails to execute.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but recently looking to do the same I came across this Gist which worked well:

https://gist.github.com/dpashouwer/4223903d3ed5783158b7e63992155649

```
library(tidyverse)

gg_to_clipboard <- function(plot = last_plot(), width = 1000, height = 600, pointsize = 40){
    win.graph(width = width, height = height, pointsize = pointsize)
    plot %>% print()
    savePlot("clipboard", type = "wmf")
    dev.off()
}

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_histogram()

gg_to_clipboard()
```

Making the function makes it very simple.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows and RStudio, you click Export, click Copy Plot to Clipboard, and Copy Plot.

Then, paste into Word or PowerPoint or whatever.

No need to change sizes unless you want to.

This is not command line, but hardly seems onerous.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the thing in RStudio is that the plot will always have the dimensions of your little "preview"-plot window. This is intended by the creators of RStudio, because most users want an exact copy of the preview plot. But I want a bigger export... and this for data that changes, so a command line "copy to clipboard in 800x600" would be a great help...