# Save plot without showing it at all

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

Is it possible to save a plot without displaying it at all ?

I made a little `ggplot` hack to be able to copy graphs to `powerpoint` easily, it copies the plot to the clipboard, but one can see the device window open and close fast, it's a bit awkward, can I avoid this ?

I'm using `windows` and `rstudio`.

**reproducible code:**

```
library(ggplot)

`-.gg` <- function(e1,e2){
  assertthat::assert_that(is.numeric(e2),
                          length(e2)<= 2)
  if(identical(e2,0)) return(invisible(NULL))
  W <- 8
  H <- 4.5
  dev.new(width=W * head(e2,1), height=H * tail(e2,1),noRStudioGD =TRUE)
  print(e1)
  savePlot("clipboard", type="wmf")
  dev.off()
  e1
}

ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10),aes(x,y)) + geom_point() - 1 - 0
```

**Edit:**

My code, and chosen solution, have issues dealing with semi-transparency.It's ok most of the time, but exceptions will be annoying.
Maybe a path to a general solution would be to save it with `tempfile` then read it into the clipboard, either through an appropriate R function, or with command line using `system` (maybe something that would open the file invisibly and copy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on Windows:  use the `win.metafile()` device.  If you give no filename, it saves to the clipboard.  So your function should be

```
library(ggplot2)

`-.gg` <- function(e1,e2){
  assertthat::assert_that(is.numeric(e2),
                          length(e2)<= 2)
  if(identical(e2,0)) return(invisible(NULL))
  W <- 8
  H <- 4.5
  win.metafile(width=W * head(e2,1), height=H * tail(e2,1))
  print(e1)
  dev.off()
  e1
}

ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10),aes(x,y)) + geom_point() - 1 - 0
```

Comment: I was too good to be true, `ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10),aes(x,y)) + geom_smooth() - 1 - 0` returns `semi-transparency is not supported on this device`. `geom_smooth` won't work completely, but it seems the `alpha` parameter is supported.

Comment: better example: `ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) + geom_smooth() - 1 - 0`

Comment: I get the same warning from your original `savePlot` code.  It's a limitation of the WMF device.  Maybe the WMF format supports transparency by now, but the device doesn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

On windows and `R 3.4.2`, using `Sys.sleep` was able to view the plot instead of blink and miss

```
`-.gg` <- function(e1,e2){
    assertthat::assert_that(is.numeric(e2),
                      length(e2)<= 2)
    if(identical(e2,0)) return(invisible(NULL))
     W <- 8
     H <- 4.5
    dev.new(width=W * head(e2,1), height=H * tail(e2,1),noRStudioGD =TRUE)
    print(e1)
    savePlot("clipboard", type="wmf")
    Sys.sleep(3) ##
    dev.off()
    e1
 }

ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10),aes(x,y)) + geom_point() - 1 - 0
```

Comment: It's a good idea as it makes it less awkward, but I'm also curious if I can actually not show it at all.