# ggsave into clipboard on Windows

Tags: r, windows, ggplot2, clipboard, ggsave

I'd like to `ggsave` a plot into my clipboard without leaving RStudio, on Windows. [Something similar has been asked about for base R graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295525/copy-r-plot-to-clipboard-with-custom-size/33124125), but I'd like to use `ggplot`+`ggsave`.

example plot operation:

```r
library(tidyverse)
{
  ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = wt)) + geom_point()
} %>%
  ggsave("plot.png", .)
```

It isn't hard, of course, to navigate to working directory/plot.png in file explorer, right-click the file and copy it, but that takes extra clicks and time.

One possible strategy might be to try and copy into the clipboard with a `system()` call afterward, e.g.:

```r
library(tidyverse)
{
  ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = wt)) + geom_point()
} %>%
  ggsave("plot.png", .) %>%
  {system( # windows command here)}
```

but I'm [having trouble finding the right windows command](https://serverfault.com/questions/162273/how-to-send-a-file-into-clipboard-from-command-line-cli), at least without downloading additional utilities. Since base R's `savePlot()` is able to save into the clipboard, there should be some way to do this, right?